# Bresenham 3D line algorithm function not working on arduino for led cube

Tags: c, algorithm, arduino

I have made an 8x8x8 LED cube and I am writing animations for it. I am trying to write a line drawing function based off of the Bresenham line algorithm. I found some code for 3D line drawing at
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bresenhams-algorithm-for-3-d-line-drawing/

The code was in python which I have more experience with. I did my best to port it over to my Arduino code (running on an adafruit itsybitsy M4). It only draws the first pixel of the line and gets stuck in an infinite loop. I have did some testing and I found it isn't crashing the program, it's a bug. My investigating also revealed that the variable "xs" is zero when it should be set to either 1 or -1. I believe that if that gets fixed it should work. I just don't know how to fix it and also why it is ignoring my extremely obvious assignment of a value to "xs"

The function "setvoxel" is how the cube's pixels are turned on. It takes the x, y, and z coordinates with z being height

```
void drawline(int x1, int y1, int z1, int x2, int y2, int z2)
{
  setvoxel(x1, y1, z1);
  int dx = abs(x2 - x1);
  int dy = abs(y2 - y1);
  int dz = abs(z2 - z1);
  int xs;
  int ys;
  int zs;
  if (x2 > x1) //=========================
  {
    int xs = 1;
  }                //troublesome code
  else
  {
    int xs = -1; 
  }            //=========================
  if (y2 > y1) //variables ys and zs might have the same problem
  {
    int ys = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    int ys = -1;
  }
  if (z2 > z1)
  {
    int zs = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    int zs = -1;
  }
  // Driving axis is the x-axis
  if (dx >= dy && dx >= dz)
  {
    int p1 = 2 * dy - dx;
    int p2 = 2 * dz - dx;
    while (x1 != x2)
    {
      x1 += xs; // if x1 here doesn't increment from xs the program gets stuck
      if (p1 >= 0)
      {
        y1 += ys;
        p1 -= 2 * dx;
      }
      if (p2 >= 0)
      {
        z1 += zs;
        p2 -= 2 * dx;
      }
      p1 += 2 * dy;
      p2 += 2 * dz;
      setvoxel(x1, y1, z1);
    }
  }
  // Driving axis is the y-axis
  else if (dy >= dx && dy >= dz)
  {
    int p1 = 2 * dx - dy;
    int p2 = 2 * dz - dy;
    while (y1 != y2)
    {
      y1 += ys;
      if (p1 >= 0)
      {
        x1 += xs;
        p1 -= 2 * dy;
      }
      if (p2 >= 0)
      {
        z1 += zs;
        p2 -= 2 * dy;
      }
      p1 += 2 * dx;
      p2 += 2 * dz;
      setvoxel(x1, y1, z1);
    }
  }
  // Driving axis is the z-axis
  else
  {
    int p1 = 2 * dy - dz;
    int p2 = 2 * dx - dz;
    while (z1 != z2)
    {
      z1 += zs;
      if (p1 >= 0)
      {
        y1 += ys;
        p1 -= 2 * dz;
      }
      if (p2 >= 0)
      {
        x1 += xs;
        p2 -= 2 * dz;
      }
      p1 += 2 * dy;
      p2 += 2 * dx;
      setvoxel(x1, y1, z1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by starting the variables as 0 and the if else statements just increment or decrement the value